# python is not recognized as an internal or external command while running batch file

Tags: python-2.7, batch-file

I am set environmental variable for python and I am able run python if I not take user input in batch file. But If I take user input I am not able to run python scripts in batch file.

```
@echo off
set /p Path="Enter Folder path in which all the timestamp files are stored: "

echo %path%

:: this is to read ip address from report folder to ipaddress.txt
dir %Path% /b /a-d > ipaddress.txt

echo %cd%

python trial.py
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Choose a variablename other than `path`.

`path` is a reservd name that contains a list of the directories to search for an executable - like `python.exe`